# The total of downloads shown in the PlayStore is counted by "Current Installations" or "Total of Installations"?

Tags: android

I noticed that when we publish an app to the Playstore, they make an average count for example: "+1000 downloads" or "+5000 downloads" and etcetera.

When I enter in the publish app area and in my apps it shows two different numbers which are `Current Installations` and `Total of Installations`.

So I would like to know which one should I take to consideration when they output in the download area of the app in the playstore. The "5000+ downloads" is referred to the Current installations or Total of installations?

Thank you.

Comment: They show the *total number of Installations* in the download area.